# transformLaserScanToPointCloud and pcl::fromROSMsgs?

Tags: ros, pcl, pcl-ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

i've taken a sensor_msgs/LaserScan and used transformLaserScanToPointCloud to get a new sensor_msgs/PointCloud.

originally my laserScan only had single values but after this, when i cout the ->points, there seems to be three values, (something, something, 0)

and since i want to be able to perform some pcl functions on my laser data i then use pcl::fromROSMsgs to take the sensor_msgs/PointCloud and transform it into a PointCloud of type PointXYZ.

and now using cout to view the ->points, there are now three values, (something, something, something).

what exaclty has happened to my original laser readings which were in meters?
i thought i could access the laser values in the PointXYZ form by using ->points._x as is shown on the struct page here... http://docs.pointclouds.org/1.3.1/structpcl_1_1_point_x_y_z.html

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/29332/transformlaserscantopointcloud-and-pcl::fromrosmsgs???/) by [liquidmonkey](https://answers.ros.org/users/1325/liquidmonkey/) on ROS Answers with karma: 37 on 2012-03-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm not really sure, what your problem is. What has happened is exactly what should have happened and as I read it also what you want.
The laser scan distances in meters have been converted into a point cloud with coordinates.
The (something, something, 0) is the point coordinates (x,y,z) and the z is 0 because there is no height information. They are still in meters.
Is this what you want?

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2012-03-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [liquidmonkey](https://answers.ros.org/users/1325/liquidmonkey/) on 2012-03-08**:
yes it is and its working, thank you :)